# Parse error, unexpected '[' only on production server

Tags: php, arrays

For the below line I am facing the error:

> Parse error,  unexpected '[' ..etc.

```
$totalEmail = array_merge($other_email,[$_SESSION['user_email']]);
```

This error is only occurring on production server, not the testing server.

Comment: Are you certain it's the EXACT same code?

Comment: Yes  , 
<?php if($agreement_type == 'bulkimporter'){
$totalEmail = array_merge($other_email,[$_SESSION['user_email']]);
 ?>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This error is only occurring on production server, not the testing server.

It's because your production server is running PHP older than 5.4 so it does not understand new array syntax (`[]`) and considers it invalid, hence syntax error you are facing. Either upgrade your production machine to use at least PHP 5.4 (but this is old too, so I'd upgrade to 7.1), or fix the code to use old array syntax (`array()`).

Comment: Thank You 

Used below now :

$totalEmail = array_merge($other_email,array($_SESSION['user_email']));